# Loop output does not yield separate rows

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm web scraping using beautifulsoup and although my loop outputs the proper information, it does not separate into distinct rows. There should be 4 columns (zip code, city, county, type) and many rows.

```py
Table2=""
for tr in Table1.find_all('tr'):
    row=""
    for tds in tr.find_all('td'):
        row=row+","+tds.text
    Table2=Table2+row[1:]
print(Table2)
```

It looks like this:

01001,Agawam,Hampden,Standard 01002,Amherst,Hampshire,Standard 01003,Amherst,Hampshire,Standard 01004,Amherst,Hampshire,P.O. Box

I want separate rows, each starting with a zip code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change  `row=row+","+tds.text` with `row = row + ",\n" + tds.text`

Comment: This just gives the same output, but only one column, so after EVERY comma, there is a new row

Answer (score 1):

I got it! Just added a "\n" here:

Table2=Table2+row[1:]+"\n"